# Force Google Chrome to store password on insecure HTTPS website (NAS)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, nas

I have a synology NAS, and I enabled https web portal for safety reasons (I enabled quickconnect). For some reason, Google Chrome thinks that the certificate it uses is insecure (`NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`) and therefore disables saving password, which is a feature I would like to have. How can I force Google Chrome to trust a website / allow saving passwords on an "insecure" website?

I had tried adding the following argument, which does nothing: `--args --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="https://192.168.1.11,https://192.168.1.15"`

Error dialog (note that this error message is *not* my question, instead it's saving passwords on this page)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this error, you need to install the root certificate and trust it on the computer. To do so manually, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516812/11031612) to a similar question.

Alternatively, you can use the "letsencrypt" option provided by Synology. Unfortunately I'm unable to verify this option as letsencrypt seems to be blocked in China.